# Mongodb 1 db for each user

Tags: mongodb

I'm new in mongodb (and in noSQL in general).

There is some use-case.

I'm going to have a database with some Records.

```
{
 title: "title1"
}
```

There 10000000000 users in the systems. And one can decide to change title from "title1" to "title2". But these changes should be available only in his own database then. After changing default data, use has his own copy of this data as if he created it by his own.

The question is:
 is good idea try to create a database on the fly as soon as user changed firs record? Is it natural for MongoDb?
 or I just may introduce new filed: "userId"

```
{
 title: "title1"
 userId: null       // null means that this global database, one for all users
}

{
 title: "title2"
 userid: user1     // this data will be visible only for user1
}
```

What I care about is SPEED. Not sure how fast it will filter the data, when each user tends to have each own copy of that data.

Comment: When you say "database", do you mean a "collection" in MongoDB terms?
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/sql-comparison/

Comment: If you are trying to create a database/collection per user, then you can't do it because of namespace constraint. Refer: `http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/limits/#namespaces`

Comment: what are possible ways then?